# Is PyMongo replica-set-aware when pod names are used instead of ip in connection URI?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have deployed mongodb replicaset and few Python Micro-services in the same kubernetes cluster where,

```
mongo-0 - PRIMARY - pod name
mongo-1 - SECONDARY - pod name
mongo-2 - SECONDARY - pod name
```

My Micro-services do not use mongodb ip to create client, rather it uses the pod name(Ex:mongo-0). My connection string from Micro-services is
`mongodb://mongo-0:27017/`
where **mongo-0** is my primary node.

My question is, if **mongo-0** goes down, can PyMongo automatically create client even if I don't specify **mongo-1** and **mongo-2** in connection string or do I have to specify

```
mongodb://mongo-0:27017,mongo-1:27017,mongo-2:27017/
```

**Note:** I am not using pod's ip anywhere rather pod name in connection URI as Micro-services are also inside cluster

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. The connection string must be like this:

```
mongodb://mongo-0:27017,mongo-1:27017,mongo-2:27017/?replicaSet=yourRepSetName
```

Then it will connect to the PRIMARY (no matter which node is currently PRIMARY)

Comment: so, you are saying I can give pod names instead of ip in connection URI?

Comment: Yes, if the pod name (no clue what this is) can be resolved to an IP - no problem. The main point is to specify `replicaSet=...`